# ASPX and IIS 8.5 - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-403

i wrote a ASPX Webapplication and generally it works great. BUT since a few days i figured out one big annoying problem with the IIS 8.5!
You can log in and browse through all sites and subsites without any problem. But after a time (about 6 mins) or when i click on the CheckBoxList on the mainsite "Report" - here [CheckBoxList Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK3zJ.jpg) - i get the Error:

> "403 Forbidden - you don't have the permission to access the
>   /Report.aspx"

On the IIS i've tested so many security configurations and nothing worked fine. The Funny thing is - sometimes i have no problem with the Webapp for 1-2 weeks and than it started all again with the 403 Forbidden Error. Meanwhile i haven't changed anything.

Application Pool is everything fine. Folder permissions and Website permissions with the IIS_USR is configured with full access. Timeout is set on 30 mins. 
I'm sorry i can't give you a link to test what i wrote because of company internal security.

Do you need any other Infos? Code elements? Settings from the IIS? Screenshots?

Hope you know what i'm looking for and thank you for any help!

Comment: You can only try failed request tracing to see which module gives you the 403. It does not seem to a default IIS or ASP.NET setting.

Comment: tracing just shows me the site has only problems with the "Post" part when i click on something on the "Report.aspx" site. The authentication in 4 ways `asp.net_sessionID, hash_asp, hash_aspx, aspx` doesn't change so the session isn't lost or anything else. I just don't understand why i can log in as often as i want and browse around without any permission problems but then i get this absolutely annoying error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't find the problem so i put the whole Website on a different Server and it works perfectly over there.

At the end i think it was/is a problem with the `https certificate`! So i changed the system from winserver 2012 and IIS 8.5 to winserver 2008 r2 with IIS 7 (if they cue in the same cert and we have the prob again i'll know it for sure).

I hope i have the chance to figure out what the problem on the old server was!

Thanks for every answer!